# The following module is missing from the file system: "post_articles"

Tags: 7

I was given a Drupal website in the form of a Drupal database running on a website and an archive containing a Drupal installation complete with a theme. Upon uploading the installation to the server and pointing it to the database, Drupal showed me a list of missing modules errors. I have installed the modules manually, except for a "post_articles" module. I have not been able to find that module anywhere and am at loss. Here is the complete error:

> User warning: The following module is missing from the file system:
> post_articles.
> For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1156 of drupal\includes\bootstrap.inc)

The website itself is unusable. I hope it is due to the missing module but not sure.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/module_missing_message_fixer

Comment: I can remove the module manually. I am concerned that the site is not working and suspect the missing module to be the cause. Does the module belong to an older version of Drupal?

Comment: just it disables the error, your module is gone, thats what error msg is saying